# Struts2 jQuery plugin java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

The issue is related to **Struts v2.3.16** and **Struts2 jQuery plugin v3.6.1**. It seems like Struts project doesn't support third party plugins like Struts2 jQuery plugin. How to fix an incompatibility of above versions? This is an exception thrown on startup

```
13:33:33 ERROR (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher:38) - Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/Workspaces/tests/jspbean/out/artifacts/exploded/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary class:com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.views.JqueryTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/D:/Workspaces/tests/jspbean/out/artifacts/exploded/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/views/TagLibrary
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Have you solved the problem? It was reported as [an](http://struts2-jquery-plugin.109969.n3.nabble.com/Issue-1066-in-struts2-jquery-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-org-apache-struts2-views-TagLibrary-td4026348.html), [issue](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1066).

Comment: The issue about [Missing interface org/apache/struts2/views/TagLibrary](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4255)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please use latest version 3.7.0 of Struts2 jQuery Plugin. This version is compatible to Struts 2.3.16.

See [Struts2 jQuery Plugin Changelog](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/Changelog) for more details.

Comment: When you've asked the question, 3.6.1 was the release version, you had no choice. Now a new version came out, fixing the bug. Then, I see two valuable answers: your one for people who do not want to upgrade, and @jogep one for people who do

Comment: Just take a look at the commits to understand why it is working now. https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/detail?r=1858

Answer (score 0):

As of Struts 2.3.16 there's no more the interface `org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary`.

You should always use [latest version](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/S2PLUGINS/jQuery+plugin+-+Easy+AJAX+and+Widget+Integration) of the plugin.