# Issue with Hibernate Search and Spring Integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, struts2, hibernate-search

I have been trying to integrate Spring with Hibernate Search but getting different exceptions with different versions.
In my pom.xml I have following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-tree-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-mobile-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also tried to get the actual version of hibernate (3.2.0 Final) from my tests so that I can easily compare the compatibility of hiberante search with my application's hiberante version.

```
String hibernateVersion = org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.VERSION;
System.out.println("Hibernate Version: "+ hibernateVersion);
```

But whenever I just add these lines into my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

and try to deploy my application then it gives me an exception

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:215 - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource ....
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.util.SoftLimitMRUCache.<init>(I)V
```

Comment: Your versions of libraries are too old, update to the latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mandatory:

- Change all Struts2 jars from `2.1.8.1` to `2.3.16`
- Change *struts2-jquery-plugin* from `3.5.1` to `3.7.0` (or [it won't work with 2.3.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232246/1654265), only with lower versions)

Suggested:

- Upgrade Hibernate to 4.x
- Upgrade Spring to 3.x

If possible, use Hibernate as JPA2 implementation, instead of using it as raw Hibernate (old way). Then you will discover that [Spring is no longer needed](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/11/from-spring-to-java-ee-6.html) (for persistence at least), especially if you are using JAVA EE 6.

P.S: you will need to upgrade also Apache Commons and other shared libraries according to the latest version, just use Maven Repository to get the proper version numbers.