# struts2-image-plugin is unable to load in struts 2.3.16.1 version

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I have been upgraded **struts 2.0 to 2.3.16.1** through the http://mvnrepository.com/ in my web application
once I deployed in tomcat server its giving following error:

```
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Projects/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/myweb/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-image-plugin-0.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:136
...

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Projects/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/myweb/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-image-plugin-0.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:136
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)

Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary class:com.aurifa.struts2.plugin.image.views.ImageTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/C:/Projects/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/myweb/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-image-plugin-0.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:136
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:169)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
```

I updated all struts related plugins, but I couldn't find any version to update **struts2-image-plugin**

Are there any **replacement for struts2-image-plugin** instead of that or any other way to resolve this issue?

Appreciate if anyone give a solution or idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following struts2 jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4255

The `TagLibrary` interface was removed from struts2 and replaced by two other interfaces.  (I'm not sure if there are going to be readded in 2.3.17)

You could update the plugin yourself to use the new interfaces if you feel brave or downgrade to 2.3.15.3 and hope the interface comes back in 2.3.17.

Comment: Yes, the class has been splitted, there is the same problem with struts2-jquery-plugin < 3.7.0 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772405/struts2-jquery-plugin-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts2-views

Comment: @tom I could resolved customizing the TagLibrary class by implementing   two other interfaces Thanks for you response.

Comment: Glad you got your application fixed since upgrading is important given there are a lot of security fixes in your new version of struts2.