# struts2 bootstrap plugin : Unable to load configuration

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, struts2

I want to use bootstrap with my struts2 application,for this reason i added this jar **struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.7.0** to `WEB-INF/LIB`, when i run the project i have this ERROR;

*Should i add any code to my `struts.xml`  ?*

```
Grave: Exception au démarrage du filtre struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/PFE/PFE_workspaces/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PfeParcAuto/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:148
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4405)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5037)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:674)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibraryDirectiveProvider class:com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap.views.BootstrapTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/D:/workspaces/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PfeParcAuto/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:148
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:222)
    at ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to add the code to your `struts.xml`. The versionning problem between struts2 core library and third party plugins started from Struts 2.3.16. Details are in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772405/struts2-jquery-plugin-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts2-views) question.

Comment: Ya i have to change the version to : struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.6.1. thanks for your help