# How to use jquery and bootstrap with struts2 2.3.15

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I have on struts2 2.3.15 application with netbeans 8.1. I have used bootstrap and jquery 1.11.x . display works well but all the forms submits twice. If I remove the jquery.js file then form works well but ui fails. tried to use bootstrap plugins for struts2 but gives error.    `Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibraryDirectiveProvider class:com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap.views.BootstrapTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/D:/server/application/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-2.0.4.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:148`

Thanks in advance.

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%><!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/sub.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <s:form action="AddNewBook"  method="post" onsubmit="return validatepost();">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr><td>Book Type </td>
                            <td >  <s:checkbox name="booktype"  data-on-text="New"
                                        data-off-text="Old" width="200px" checked="true" />

                            </td><td>Binding </td>
                            <td><s:textfield cssClass="form-control" name="binding"  placeholder="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr> <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><s:submit name="submit" cssClass="btn btn-success  btn-block" value="Post your book" />
                            </td><td></td>
                            <td></td>


                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </s:form>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

<script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="javascripts/docs.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="javascripts/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/highlight.js"></script>
<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="javascripts/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="javascripts/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="javascripts/minifunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="javascripts/securetext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="javascripts/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Show us how you do submit forms

Comment: Hi Andrea. Its a sample piece of code. Please note that If I remove jquery.min.js all works well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struts2 jQuery plugin java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772405/struts2-jquery-plugin-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts2-views)

Comment: I'm using all js,css files for jquery and bootstrap. not any struts2 plugin. is it a good way to use bootstrap in struts2.

Comment: `Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster` O_O

Comment: Yes I Have placed , But the all the forms submit twice.