# Struts2 standard JQuery library Upgrade

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have developed a project that use below

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

and using the struts2-core-2.5.20.jar
and added the struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-4.0.3 also
but when i check on the browser network panel still loading a old library

```
http://localhost:8080/JSLibTest/struts/js/base/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
```

how can i upgrade to latest.
below are my libraries
i have found that struts2-jquery-plugin-4.0.3.jar library contains the jquery-2.2.4.min.js but is there any latest versions other that this.
[meaven list](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery/struts2-jquery-plugin)
[lib list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ARX1.png)

Comment: AFAIK the latest jQuery plugins are 4.1 but IIRC are [still using old jQuery](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/tree/release/4.1.x/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/base).

Comment: That said, I also tend to recommend just writing the JavaScript--packaged components, especially in the S2 projects, tend to lag far behind current state of the art, in multiple ways.

Comment: You didn't clarify your problem. Either you use a plugin, or not use. The version of JQuery is integrated with the project. For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20772405/573032) question.